# Gesture recording, save and re use

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uigesturerecognizer

i just develop a software, for security reason i want to save user's gesture like circle or cross or something like that.. Is there an open source sample for monotouch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think there are ready-to-use solutions for this kind of stuff. You may write a custom gesture recognizer which records the touch events as a time series *p(t)*, where *p(t)* is the *(x,y)* position on the screen at time *t*. Once you've acquired the time series (let's call this the user's *gesture fingerprint*), you would compare it to the reference fingerprint using some distance measure, and accept it within some threshold.

The tricky part is defining the distance measure, because your system should accept the correct gesture with reasonable tolerance (low false negative rate), but on the other hand, it shouldn't accept any other gestures (low false positive rate). There's usually a tradeoff between these two quantities (false negative rate vs false positive rate), and you would tailor your pattern recognition system's tolerance parameters to your specific needs (for security applications, you should go minimizing the false positive rate).

To reliably implement such a system, you should be familiar with digital signal processing and have a good grasp of machine learning / pattern recognition.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin has some [documentation on touch](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/touch/part_1_touch_in_ios/) along with a [walkthrough](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/touch/part_2_ios_touch_walkthrough/). In addition there is a recipe on [using gesture recognizers](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/input/touch/drag_rotate_image/). Hopefully that can help you get started.